# Java replace $^{}

Tags: java, regex, string

I am writing a program that allows users to input variable names that they can then use in other Strings. For example, if the user enters:

```
$token aslkdjfna98y
```

A mapping is created for key "token" and value "aslkdjfna98y". I then want to add this token variable in a URL by specifying that it should be swapped out using this syntax:

```
http://www.example.com/getThing?token=$^{token}
```

So here, I would like to swap `$^{token}` with my mapped value *aslkdjfna98y*.

I have tried various `String.replace` and `String.replaceAll` calls, however I am currently getting stuck in a loop - where it's known that the String contains the text *$^{token}*, but I cannot replace the text. Here is where I am struggling:

```
if (request.contains("$^{"))
    {
        //handle variables
        for (String s : variables.keySet())
        {
            String str = String.format(Locale.US, "$^{%s}", s);
            while(request.contains(str))
            {
                //Stuck Here
                request = request.replace(String.format(Locale.US, "$^{%s}", s), variables.get(s));
            }
        }
    }
```

This could ideally be simplified down to:

```
request.replaceAll(regex, str);
```

How can I correctly replace the characters, or how can I improve this to use `replaceAll`?

Comment: Why all the downvotes? I would appreciate it if at least someone explained...

Comment: Almost certainly because you've essentially said "I can't be bothered to read up on this myself"...

Answer (score 4):

Enclose the String in `\\Q` and `\\E`. This switches off all special characters in Java regexes:

```
request = request.replace(String.format(Locale.US, "\\Q$^{%s}\\E", s), variables.get(s));
```

Comment: Thanks. I will use this in the future for sure! I also realized that most simply - I am not reassigning *request* after performing the replace.

Answer (score 0):

```
"$^{token}"
```

im confused whats suppose to be in the token field...

any letters/num?

```
"$^{[a-zA-Z0-9]*}"
```

Um.....

a certain amount(8) of letters/numbs.

```
"$^{[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}}"
```

**depending on the language you are using you might need to escape { $ and ^**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to simplify the code down to this simple block:

```
if (variables.get(s) != null) {
    request = request.replaceAll(Log.format("\\Q$^{%s}\\E", s), variables.get(s));
}
else {
    Log.err("No variable \"%s\" set", s);
}
```